# How Do I Match Everything After a Character

Tags: c#, regex

I almost have this answer. I want to match everything following a colon and a space.

So if I have these lines

```
What is your name: Alain
What is your major: Computer Science
```

I would like to capture `"Alain"` and `"Computer Science"`.

I have this regex

```
(?<=:)\s*\w*
```

That captures a white space followed by my name and it captures `" Alain"` and `" Computer"`. How can I get rid of the leading white space?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `(?<=:\s*).*$` which will capture after the colon and space, up to the end.  Depending on your regex options, `$` can mean end of line or end of string.

Comment: arg i hate edits! i should have looked

Comment: Why regex? A simple `Split` would do.

Comment: Are Split's simpler?  Are they faster? Sorry I only have a year of school under my me.

Answer (score 2):

```
: (.*)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hafrKL/1)

(This regex is implementation agnostic, and should work with any regex library)

If you are using a capture group, this will capture the contents you are looking for, but will match the colon and space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split as suggested above. But if you really have to use Regex, the following works on your string.

```
string line1 = "What is your name: Alain";
Regex rgex = new Regex(@"(?<=:\s)(.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Match match = rgex.Match(line1);            

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name= " + match.Value);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for the delay. Had a calculus test to study for.  Everything stopped for that.

Answer (score 0):

There might be less verbose ways of doing this, however this works

```
(?<=What is your name: )(.*)(?= What is your major:)|(?<=What is your major: )(.*)
```

**Update**

Since its multi line (courtesy of Ben Voigt) with the added word boundary

```
(?<=:\s*)\b.*$
```

**Example**

```
var pattern = @"(?<=:\s*)\b.*$";
var input = "What is your name: Alain \r\nWhat is your major: Computer Science";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[**You can test it here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KcJdmC)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) and split by a colon and zero or more whitespaces [`:\s*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3a%5cs*&i=What+is+your+name%3a+Alain%0d%0aWhat+is+your+major%3a+Computer+Science)

```
string[] lines = { "What is your name: Alain" , "What is your major: Computer Science " };                        
string pattern = @":\s*";
foreach (string str in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Split(str, pattern)[1]);
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TXT80367)